# Finding closest points without duplicates and given distance threshold

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, geospatial

Given a bunch of latitudes and longitudes stored as Points, I would like to determine the points that are closest to each point given some maximum threshold in meters. This is my first stab at this:

```
DECLARE @ThresholdInMeters FLOAT = 1000000.0;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Points1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Points1
CREATE TABLE #Points1
    (
      PointId INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      Point GEOGRAPHY NULL
    ) 

DECLARE @LowerLatitude FLOAT;
DECLARE @UpperLatitude FLOAT;
DECLARE @RandomLatitude FLOAT;
DECLARE @LowerLongitude FLOAT;
DECLARE @UpperLongitude FLOAT;
DECLARE @RandomLongitude FLOAT;
DECLARE @Counter INT;

SET @LowerLatitude = -90 
SET @UpperLatitude = 90 
SET @LowerLongitude = -180
SET @UpperLongitude = 180

SET @Counter = 100;
WHILE ( @Counter > 0 )
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @RandomLatitude = ( ( @UpperLatitude - @LowerLatitude - 1 )
                                    * RAND() + @LowerLatitude );
        SELECT  @RandomLongitude = ( ( @UpperLongitude - @LowerLongitude - 1 )
                                     * RAND() + @LowerLongitude );

        INSERT  INTO #Points1
                SELECT  GEOGRAPHY::Point(@RandomLatitude, @RandomLongitude,
                                         4326)

        SET @Counter = @Counter - 1;
    END 

SELECT  
    Points1.PointId AS StartPointId,
    Points2.PointId AS EndPointId,
    Points1.Point.STDistance(Points2.Point) AS Distance
FROM #Points1 AS Points1
INNER JOIN #Points1 AS Points2 ON Points1.PointId <= Points2.PointId
WHERE Points1.Point.STDistance(Points2.Point) < @ThresholdInMeters
```

Any ideas on how to potentially improve this, especially in performance? All indices are already set.

Answer (score 2):

## Style

### Remove unneccessary parentheses

You don't need parentheses around the condition for the `WHILE`
loop.  You can just write `WHILE @counter > 0`.

Also, the extra sets of parentheses around the random numbers are
superfluous.  If you leave them off, the line will be a bit less
daunting.

### Don't break the line in the middle of a concept

That is, in the `SELECT @RandomLatitude` line, the statement breaks
just before the `*` operator.  As it has a higher precedence than
the `+`, this can be a bit misleading.  Either don't break, use
parentheses (if really unavoidable) or break before the `+`:

```
SELECT @RandomLatitude = ( @UpperLatitude - @LowerLatitude - 1 ) * RAND()
                         + @LowerLatitude;
SELECT @RandomLongitude = ( @UpperLongitude - @LowerLongitude - 1 ) * RAND()
                          + @LowerLongitude;
```

### Merge variable declaration and initialisation

Where possible, declare a variable just before it is used, and
initialise it there as well:

```
DECLARE @LowerLatitude FLOAT = -90;
DECLARE @UpperLatitude FLOAT = 90;
DECLARE @LowerLongitude FLOAT = -180;
DECLARE @UpperLongitude FLOAT = 180;

DECLARE @Counter INT = 1000;
WHILE @Counter > 0
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @RandomLatitude FLOAT = ( @UpperLatitude - @LowerLatitude - 1 ) * RAND()
                                    + @LowerLatitude
    DECLARE @RandomLongitude FLOAT = ( @UpperLongitude - @LowerLongitude - 1 ) * RAND()
                                     + @LowerLongitude
    -- ...
```

## Performance

You mention that the indices are already set. I assume that means that
it is not possible to add a [Spatial Index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929109.aspx), *or* a primary key.
Although I would strongly suggest adding a primary key constraint to
the temp table in this example:

```
CREATE TABLE #Points1
    ( PointId INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    , Point GEOGRAPHY NULL
    );
```

Unfortunately, without a Spatial Index or changes to the result
requirements (you'd need a `TOP n` clause and an `ORDER BY` on the
STDistance column), there is no choice but to check each point against
all others, which will give a large join of which I don't know how to
improve the performance.

Small point: you may gain a smaller result (only in number of rows) if
you leave out the distance from each point to itself:

```
INNER JOIN Points1 AS Points2 ON Points1.PointId < Points2.PointId
```

but that might not fit your requirements.